# Ruby print out only the class methods (and not inherited methods)

Tags: ruby

I wish to only print out the methods that are declared in the class. This does the trick:

```rb
p (
  Float.instance_methods - 
  Object.instance_methods - 
  Numeric.instance_methods
  ).count

p (
  Float.instance_methods - 
  Object.instance_methods - 
  Numeric.instance_methods
  )

STDOUT:
12
[:+, :-, :*, :/, :**, :to_f, :to_i, :nan?, :infinite?, :finite?, :to_r, :rationalize]
```

But isn't there an easier way to get these methods?

---

bonus info

```rb
p Float.methods.count # 117

p Float.instance_methods.count # 126

p Float.class.methods.count # 120
```

Comment: What about overridden methods like e.g. `zero?` which is defined by both, `Numeric` and `Float`?

Comment: Good point. However the use case I intend to use it for is for the classes I define myself and I plan to not do any overwrites (dangerous practice)

Comment: In that case, `YourClass.instance_methods(false)` should return the own instance methods, i.e. without inherited ones.

Comment: arhh.. okay - tried that but got confused that it print `47` for `Float.instance_methods(false).count` but that because of the overwrites that gets excluded by my example.

Comment: If you write you comment as an answer then I'll mark it as solved 

Comment: BTW, overwrite != override. The former refers to replacing a given method by re-opening a class and re-defining it – a so-called [monkey patch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monkey_patch) (can indeed be dangerous). The latter means implementing a method with the same name in a subclass, providing subclass-specific behavior. This doesn't affect or alter the superclass method, which can even be called via `super`. [Method overriding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_overriding) is a core concept of OOP. Without it, you couldn't even define your own `to_s` or `inspect` methods.

Comment: Thank you for correcting me and pointing out the differences

Comment: https://rubymonk.com/learning/books/4-ruby-primer-ascent/chapters/37-classes-inheritance/lessons/88-redefining-overriding-and-super#255

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> `methods(regular=true) → array`
> Returns a list of the names of public
> and protected methods of obj. This will include all the methods
> accessible in obj's ancestors. If the optional parameter is false, it
> returns an array of obj's public and protected singleton methods, the
> array will not include methods in modules included in obj.
> - https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.1/Object.html#method-i-methods

[`Module#instance_methods`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.1/Module.html#method-i-instance_methods) has the exact same signature.

```
module Bannable
  def ban!
    @banned = true
  end
end

class Parent
  include Bannable

  def a_parent_instance_method
  end

  def self.a_parent_class_method
  end
end

class Child < Parent
  def a_child_instance_method
  end

  def self.a_child_class_method
  end
end
```

```
irb(main):024:0> Child.methods(false)
=> [:a_child_class_method]
irb(main):025:0> Child.instance_methods(false)
=> [:a_child_instance_method]
```